# How can I integrate Angular 2 and jQuery draggable to update the model on drag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui

I have a simple node object with x, y and ID. I render it like this:

```
<div class="node" *ngFor="let node of nodes" [ngStyle]="{'left': node.x + 'px', 'top': node.y + 'px'}"></div>

ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(".node").draggable({});
}
```

The issue is that after I actual drag the nodes around the screen, the x/y properties don't get updated on the model. I need to do some other things while the node is being dragged, so i'd ideally like to execute some function while the node is being dragged. I know jqueryUI exposes drag: function(event, ui){}, but from inside that function I can't access the model of the node that's actually being dragged.

What's the proper way to handle this? Is there some way to go from the jQuery object being dragged to the model, or is there a more Angular way to do this?